# JavaFX - get the height of a Label item in pixels (or vertically align a label using the center of its height)

Tags: java, javafx, label

I have a program that draws a chart with an axis with values.
The values need to be drawn every 'y' pixels.

As shown in image, the black lines show where those values are drawn.
A corresponding Label is drawn next to each axis value.

The problem is that with no displacement the origin is taken at the upper left corner of the label, so the text is not vertically aligned with the line.

In order to fix that I am thinking in getting the height of the label and manually offseting the y position for the label.

**How can I get the height of the label in pixels?**

[image: Label vertical alignment]

This is the source code used to draw the lines and the labels:

```java
public void drawAxis() {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        long y_pos = 0;
        y_pos = i*100;
        Line gridTick = new Line(0, y_pos, 20, y_pos);

        Label gridLabel = new Label(getStringFromValue(y_pos));
        gridLabel.setTranslateX(30);
        gridLabel.setTranslateY(y_pos);

        rightAxisPanel.getChildren().add(gridTick);
        rightAxisPanel.getChildren().add(gridLabel);
    }
}
```

Comment: put the line and label in a hbox.

Comment: @Sedrick I don't think this yields the desired behavior: It would fix the top of the `Label`, not the `Line`'s vertical position. Adjusting the text size would move the line vertically which is not the desired behavior for axis markings.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That includes the one on the other question about parent. I use parent all the time but only to load FXML. I guess I never ran into the problem of trying to get it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set make sure the label size is bigger than actually needed and the bounds are symetrical to the y coordinates of the line. Let `Label` deal with the alignment.

Assuming the subclass of `Parent` you extend does not modify the layout position, you can do

```
public void drawAxis() {
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        double y_pos = i*100;
        Line gridTick = new Line(0, y_pos, 20, y_pos);

        Label gridLabel = new Label(getStringFromValue(y_pos));
        gridLabel.setLayoutX(30);

        // make sure label bounds range from y_pos-25 to y_pos+25 vertically
        gridLabel.setLayoutY(y_pos-25);
        gridLabel.setPrefHeight(2*25);
        gridLabel.setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        // set text alignment in label area
        gridLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        rightAxisPanel.getChildren().addAll(gridTick, gridLabel);
    }
}
```

This assumes that you do not use font sizes that require more than 50 pixels to display vertically.